# Реализация "Купить" конкретный товар, с помощью модального окна Bootstrap 4.5.3 в Laravel 8

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, modal

Всем привет! В общем практикуюсь на `Laravel 8`, есть корзина куда можно добавлять товары и спокойно из нее оформить заказ. Но так же я добавил кнопку купить на карточке каждого товара. При нажатии открывается `модальное окно`, по идее хочу чтобы там отображалось название, картинка, количество данного типа товара и общая стоимость. Ну и потом, при оформлении заказа, чтобы можно было эти данные передать в БД, в таблицу `Orders`.

Но, вот столкнулся с проблемой. Куда писать логику, сессию и т.д.? У модального окна ведь нет отдельного роута (подгружаю через `@include`), значит и с контроллера к нему не обратиться. Сразу пришел в голову `View Composers`, но опять таки, что то не то, т.к. нет роута, я не могу обратиться к `$id`(для обычных страниц можно роуту задать `url` типа `product/{id}` и потом по этому `id` искать нужный товар `$product = Product::find($id)`.

Перерыл половину интернета, вроде были похожие вопросы, но все равно не допер. Я не прошу за меня сделать, просто дайте направление, как это без заморочек сделать?

И в целом какая логика реализации? Я должен создать сессию, добавить туда через `ajax` текущий товар, потом при оформлении передать данные из сессии в `БД`?

Если нужно привести какой-нибудь код, сообщите.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Просто создайте отдельный контроллер для модального окна заказов например `ModalOrderController` в web.php пропишите роут для модальных окон например `Route::get('/modal/{order_id}', [ModalOrderController::class, 'modal_order'])->name('modal_order');`.  В целом для модального окна нет отдельного url как у обычной странички но ведь в модальном окне у вас наверняка есть форма как минимум для количества товара и ети данные отправляются на сервер для обработки и сохранения. Относительно логики реализации есть несколько вариантов где хранить данные корзины - сесия/куки/сразу база данных...

Comment: @Dmitriy Kondratiuk, а в контроллере что возвращать? Если для обычной страницы я ее view возвращаю, то здесь что?

Comment: Ну смотрите допустим у вас корзина реализована на сесиях. Вы открыли модальное окно в нем есть форма с кнопкой или просто кнопка добавить товар. При нажатиии на кнопку вы или отправляете форму на адрес где она будет обработана или делаете аякс запрос на тот же адрес чтобы не перезагружать страницу. Запрос уходит в контроллер где вы его обрабатываете (создаете сесию). После обработки запроса вы делаете редирект обратно на ту страницу с которой пришёл запрос или в случае с использованием аякса вы возращаете например сообщение товар успешно добавлен в корзину.

Comment: @Dmitriy Kondratiuk, понял, спасибо большое!

Comment: @Dmitriy Kondratiuk, кстати немного не так описал. У меня есть карточка товара, на ней кнопка купить. Когда я её нажимаю открывается модальное окно и по идее сверху должно показывать картинку, название и количество и общую сумму, а под ними уже форма и кнопка "оформить заказ", нажатие на которую отправит данные заказа в БД. Я пока не совсем понимаю каким образом мне переменную передать, если вьюхи своей нет.

Comment: У вас по сути вюха это модальное окно, в нем есть форма в формы есть (action) адрес на который отправляется данные с формы или в случае аякс запроса в самом запросе вы можете указать куда отправлять данные. Так как у вас форма то данные отправляются post запросом для этого вам нужно создать путь для обработки формы `Route::post . . .` куда будете отправлять данные с формы. Чтобы передать айди товара можно создать скрытое поле где будет указано айди.